# The record couldn’t be saved CANNOT_EXECUTE_FLOW_TRIGGER

Tags: approval-process, chatter-feed-tracking, dmlexception, trailhead

I am trying to Complete the [Trailhead Challenge of Chatter basics](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/chatter/chatter_approvals) (Approving Records from the Feed  )

While checking the Challenge I am getting Error

> Challenge Not yet complete... here's what's wrong: 
>   There was an unexpected error in your org which is preventing this assessment check from completing: System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_EXECUTE_FLOW_TRIGGER, The record couldn’t be saved because it failed to trigger a flow. A flow trigger failed to execute the flow with version ID 30128000000LoRJ. Contact your administrator for help.: []

I tried to investigate the debug log 
[image]

Then I tried to insert case from Anonymous window

```
Case c  = new Case(subject='a');
insert c;
```

It was also thrwing the same Exception

> Line: 2, Column: 1
>   System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_EXECUTE_FLOW_TRIGGER, The record couldn’t be saved because it failed to trigger a flow. A flow trigger failed to execute the flow with version ID 30128000000LoRJ. Contact your administrator for help.: []

Comment: Check if there is any process builder active. deacctive that and try.

Comment: Thanks @Tushar . It worked. I checked all possibilities. Only Process builder was left. that was older version which was active. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root cause here is in process builder if we are using some fields and in test class data those fields are blank then we get this error if we create data which have all fields populated used in test class then you will not face this error.

Also if you face same error with your live system then you should have received an email. In the email SF provide details which field or action causing the issue.

Comment: Yeah It worked.

Comment: i am facing this when running test class.it go away after deactivate it but is this the elegant way?so in the production we need to deactivate process builder everytime we want to deploy the class?

Comment: @unidha can you post this as new question and provide some details. You can refer this question.

Comment: Deactivating a Process builder flow should not be a solution

Comment: @sskular i have already added few updates in my answer. You should check that.

Answer (score 4):

If anyone is still looking for a better answer in this thread... here you go.

You might get this error if the SObject (that you're inserting ) has an active Process Builder that expects certain fields to have values and those field values are NOT supplied  before inserting them.

Try to pack all the necessary fields for the SObject that are required by process builder. You don't need to deactivate the process builder

If you have record types set for that SObject make sure you supply the appropriate record type while packing field values.

Answer (score 1):

We may not deactivate process builder every time we clash with this kind of exceptions as in most of the cases, fields of the respective object that are being used by this process builder have no values provided while creation or on update of object. If we could provide legitimate value to those fields, it will surely work...!

Thanks...!